# JAVA JTextField verification user input email

Tags: java, jframe, verify

I need to verify that the user input has both the characters '@' and '.' in their email address.

So far I've figured out how to verify one character(the '@' char). But how do I make it so that the program checks for two characters in the same textfield (both '@' and '.') ?

```
if (evt.getSource() == submitButton) {

            String get = emailText.getText().toString();
            char a = '@';
            char dot = '.';
            String message = "";
            int count = 0;

            for(int i=0; i<get.length(); i++) {

                if(get.charAt(i)== a){
                    count++;
                    message = "This is valid email";

                    if(count>=2){
                        message = "this isn't valid email";
                    }
                }else{
                    message = "This isn't valid";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very basic check for verification of email

```
int atposition = 0, dotposition = 0, flag = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < get.length(); i++) {

    if(get.charAt(i) == a) {
                count++;
                atposition = i;

                if(count >= 2) {
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
    }

   if (get.charAt(i) == '.') {
                dotposition = i;
    }
 }

 if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= get.length() || flag == 1) {
    message = "Not a valid e-mail address";
 } else {
    message = "valid email-id";
 }
 return message;
```

there can be more than one `dot` in an email..see if it works for you

Comment: hey, another question, in this program the following needs to be done

"each field will have verification. The verification will be triggered when the user moves focus to another area from the textfield they are currently working on."

There are 4 fields: name, phone#, address, and Email. Can you explain to me how this can be achieved? Do I use Mouse Event Handling?

Comment: i have not used JAVA that much for `GUI`..so i don't know much about inbuilt functions of JAVA..if it were `PHP` and `JAVASCRIPT` i could have told

Comment: you can ask this question in another thread..maybe someone can help